# How to iterate through this list to subtract any elements that are not a two-pair? (Python)

Tags: python, list, loops

```
list = [('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C')]
```

here is the list I am trying to reduce to only containing pairs and not the single or triple.

Comment: Don't name your variable `list`, by the way, or it becomes more difficult to access the built-in function `list`.

Comment: Radar detected :D